# ReportLab. int object has no attribute decode

Tags: python, django

Делаю PDF на основе данных из БД.
возникает ошибка 'int' object has no attribute 'decode'

вью:

```
def spisok_pdf(request, title="Список покупок", aka=""): # генерация pdf
...
sp = Model.objects.filter(user_spisok__username=me).order_by('-id')[0]
response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=try.pdf'
    c = canvas.Canvas(response)
    MyFontObject = ttfonts.TTFont('Arial', 'arial.ttf')
    pdfmetrics.registerFont(MyFontObject)
    c.setStrokeColor(brown)
    c.setFont('Times-Roman', 10)
    c.drawString(25, 820, "www.")
    c.setStrokeColor(gray)
    c.grid([0.3*inch, 5.4*inch, 6.4*inch, 7.4*inch], [#0.2*inch, 0.4*inch, 0.6*inch,
                                                      0.8*inch, 1*inch, 1.2*inch, 1.4*inch, 1.6*inch, 1.8*inch, 2*inch, 2.2*inch,
                                                      2.4*inch, 2.6*inch, 2.8*inch, 3*inch, 3.2*inch, 3.4*inch, 3.6*inch, 3.8*inch, 4*inch, 4.2*inch, 4.4*inch,
                                                      4.6*inch, 4.8*inch, 5*inch, 5.2*inch, 5.4*inch, 5.6*inch, 5.8*inch, 6*inch, 6.2*inch, 6.4*inch, 6.6*inch,
                                                      6.8*inch, 7*inch, 7.2*inch, 7.4*inch, 7.6*inch, 7.8*inch, 8*inch, 8.2*inch, 8.4*inch, 8.6*inch, 8.8*inch,
                                                      9*inch, 9.2*inch, 9.4*inch, 9.6*inch, 9.8*inch, 10*inch, 10.2*inch, 10.4*inch, 10.6*inch, 10.8*inch, 11*inch
                                                      ])
 c.setFont('Arial', 11)
    c.drawString(160, 780, "Наименование")
    c.setFont('Arial', 11)
    c.drawString(403, 780, "Кол-во")
    c.setFont('Arial', 11)
    c.drawString(480, 780, "Цена")
    # ДАННЫЕ
    c.setFont('Arial', 11)
    c.drawString(30, 765, sp.obj_1)
    c.setFont('Arial', 11)
    c.drawString(395, 765, sp.number_1)
    c.setFont('Arial', 11)
    c.drawString(466, 765, sp.price_1)
    # ИТОГ
    c.setFont('Arial', 14)
    c.drawString(403, 40, "Итог:")
    c.setFont('Arial', 14)
    c.drawString(473, 40, itog)
    c.showPage()
    c.save()
    return response
```

Модель состоит из CharField и InegerField
Не могу понять почему такая ошибка вообще может быть? При чем CharField выводит корректно,а ругается походу на IntegerField .
могу дополнить данные , если требуется
использую Reportlab

```
    Traceback:
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
132. response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\nato4ka\shops\views.py" in spisok_pdf
100. c.drawString(395, 765, sp.number_1)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\reportlab\pdfgen\canvas.py" in drawString
1503. text = text.decode('utf-8')

Exception Type: AttributeError at /shops/spisok/print/
Exception Value: 'int' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
c.drawString(395, 765, str(sp.number_1))
```